# Return text from radio buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to create a search bar in kivy with only pure python. Is there any way to return a certain string to a function from selecting a radio button

This is a small snippet from my program. It would be helpful if you could answer using pure python codes

```
class avbl_bk(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(avbl_bk,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        blayout=BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        check=BoxLayout()
        search_layout=BoxLayout(spacing=10,padding=5)
        search_label=Label(text="Search: ",size_hint_x=0.5)
        search_box=TextInput(multiline=False,font_size=40,size_hint_x=0.8)
        search=Button(text="Search",size_hint=(.3,0.8))
        chk1=CheckBox(group='1')
        chk2=CheckBox(group='1')
        chk3=CheckBox(group='1')
        chk4=CheckBox(group='1')
        chk5=CheckBox(group='1')
        chk6=CheckBox(group='1')
        filters=["ISBN","Book","Genre","Author","Publisher","Copies"]
        for i in range(6):
            check.add_widget(Label(text=filters[i]))
            check.add_widget(eval(("chk"+str(i+1))))
        search_layout.add_widget(search_label)
        search_layout.add_widget(search_box)
        search_layout.add_widget(check)
        search_layout.add_widget(search)
        blayout.add_widget(search_layout)
        self.add_widget(blayout)
```

Comment: You can bind to the `active` property of the `CheckBox` to do anything you want. Have a look at the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem 2 - Pass selected radio button's text to search button

> I wanted to use the string to perform a query in my database and
>   display it when i press the search button. How would I do it then?

### Solution 2

- [Declare a class attribute](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#declaration-of-a-property), `search_by` of [`StringProperty`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.StringProperty) type
- Use [`App.get_running_app()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app) function to access the app instance
- Populate `search_type` with `instance.text` in `on_active()` method
- Use `search_by` in the search / database query function

#### Snippets

```
class CustomCheckBox(CheckBox):
    text = StringProperty('')

    def on_active(self, instance, value):
        if value:
            print(f'\tThe checkbox text={instance.text} is active')
            App.get_running_app().root.search_by = instance.text


class avbl_bk(Screen):
    search_by = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(avbl_bk, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
```

## Problem 1 - Return text from radio buttons

> Is there any way to return a certain string to a function from
>   selecting a radio button

### Solution 1

The solution is as follow:

1. Create a `class CustomCheckBox` with inheritance of `CheckBox` widget
2. Declare a class attribute, `text` of `StringProperty` type
3. Implement `on_active` event
4. Instantiate `CustomCheckBox` with `group='1'` and `text=text=filters[i]` inside the `for` loop

#### Snippets

```
class CustomCheckBox(CheckBox):
    text = StringProperty('')

    def on_active(self, instance, value):
        if value:
            print(f'\tThe checkbox text={instance.text} is active')


class avbl_bk(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(avbl_bk, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ...
        search = Button(text="Search", size_hint=(.3, 0.8))

        filters = ["ISBN", "Book", "Genre", "Author", "Publisher", "Copies"]
        for i in range(6):
            check.add_widget(Label(text=filters[i]))
            check.add_widget(CustomCheckBox(group='1', text=filters[i]))

        search_layout.add_widget(search_label)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks! but say i wanted to use the string to perform a query in my database and display it when i press the search button. How would I do it then?

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Please refer to updated post for solution to your second problem.